# How set the type of node editor window to "compositing"?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I can change the window type to "node editor" with

```
bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0].screen.areas[0].type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
```

but how to set it type to "compositing"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mouse over the property you will see it is the [`SpaceNodeEditor.tree_type`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.SpaceNodeEditor.html#bpy.types.SpaceNodeEditor.tree_type) property you want to set.  The screen is split into areas, these areas have regions, toolbar header etc, and spaces.  I've put a print statement in to show the spaces for the area.  To get the space associated with an area use `area.spaces.active` or `context.space_data` (after changing the `context.area.type`)

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

area = context.area

area.type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
# the context area is now a node editor
# the space has the tree_type enum

for sp in area.spaces:
    print(sp, sp.type, "has tree_treetype", hasattr(sp, "tree_type"))

space = context.space_data
# or better still
space = area.spaces.active
# set to compositing    
space.tree_type = 'CompositorNodeTree'
```

To find `space.tree_type = 'CompositorNodeTree'` run code above with `space.tree_type = 'Blah'` which gives the options in the error message.

```
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: 
enum "Blah" not found in 
('ShaderNodeTree', 'CompositorNodeTree', 'TextureNodeTree')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me as: bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0].screen.areas[0].spaces.active.tree_type = 'CompositorNodeTree'